# Colored text and icons in notification bar in Android Nougat

Tags: android, android-layout

How to get colored text and icons like in the Twitter app ? In my app the color is shown in grey and white.. how to change this?? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom `contentView` on your Notification Builder

> To define a custom notification layout, start by instantiating a
>   RemoteViews object that inflates an XML layout file. Then, instead of
>   calling methods such as setContentTitle(), call setContent(). To set
>   content details in the custom notification, use the methods in
>   RemoteViews to set the values of the view's children:
>
> Create an XML layout for the notification in a separate file. You can
>   use any file name you wish, but you must use the extension .xml In
>   your app, use RemoteViews methods to define your notification's icons
>   and text. Put this RemoteViews object into your 
>   NotificationCompat.Builder by calling setContent(). Avoid setting a
>   background Drawable on your RemoteViews object, because your text
>   color may become unreadable.

and the code is as follow:

```
RemoteViews mycontentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
mycontentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.myimage, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
mycontentView.setTextViewText(R.id.mytitle, "Custom Notification");

NotificationCompat.Builder myBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
.setContent(mycontentView);

Notification myNotification = myBuilder.build();
myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
myNotificationManager.notify(1, myNotification);
```

where `R.layout.notification` is your custom layout file

and the layout file is below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:padding="12dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/myimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Testing"
        android:id="@+id/mytitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/myimage"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more simpler and shorter way to do it:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary));
```

Check  [this link](https://medium.com/exploring-android/android-n-introducing-upgraded-notifications-d4dd98a7ca92) for reference. Cheers !!!